# Uncaught TypeError: no method 'responsiveSlides'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slideshow

I'm trying to implement the responsiveSlides plugin on a Wordpress theme. I've got the necessary css, jquery and javascript files linked and in the order below and there are no other jquery/javascript plugins.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/responsiveslides.css" />
<script src="<?bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/responsiveslides.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then I included a script tag calling the function to initiate the slideshow but got the error

```
<script>
$(function () {

  $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
    maxwidth: 800,
    speed: 50
  });

});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'responsiveSlides'

I replaced "responsiveSlides" with "Hide" to test if jquery is working and it did. It appears that I have all the necessary files linked (responsiveSlides.min.js...etc) as shown in the  browser developer tool and in the proper order. Not exactly sure why this is not working. If you can provide any pointer it is much appreciated.

Comment: You say you have all the necessary files linked, but are you sure the paths are correct? Can you use the Developer Tools or "View Page Source" to make sure the URLs return the actual content?

Comment: Yep I've checked and the js files are loaded and return the actual file. Unless the file itself is outdated/corrupted otherwise that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: You're absolutely sure? This is usually the problem for this error - the plugin wasn't actually loaded, because it was forgotten or URL misspelled. How are you checking to see the files return the actual content?

Comment: show page source and clicked on the files.

Comment: So in Developer Tools, are you able to view what files your page is requesting when the page loads? You should obviously see the 3 files you are using being requested. Are there any other Javascript files you see or know about?

Comment: figured out what the issue was. When I installed the wordpress I also installed twitter bootstrap plugin for layout styling. And bootstrap's js file is causing a conflict with this slider plugin. I removed the bootstrap plugin and it worked. So now I suppose the solution in the answer should resolve that. But it is not, maybe I am not implementing that script correctly? I just replaced what I have in the script tag with what's below.

Comment: You don't need to use the answer. If your current script works, use that. The answer was for aliasing `jQuery` (which should basically always refer to the jQuery library) as `$` inside of that scope, to make sure that every time you use `$` inside of that scope, it **does** refer to the jQuery library (and not things like the Prototype library).

Comment: Got it, issue is resolved, thanks @Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
(function ($) {

  $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
    maxwidth: 800,
    speed: 50
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. this will work if there's a conflict with `$`; i.e., another library is using that variable.

Comment: @Mark I know, probably that's the root cause.

Comment: This is the way I've seen recommended on jQuery plugin development page on the jQuery wiki. Nice.

Comment: `I replaced "responsiveSlides" with "Hide" to test if jquery is working and it did` . Also, it didn't throw an error on the `document.ready` alias of `$(function () {});` and that's on the page first. I don't think it's a library problem. I could be wrong though

Comment: Thanks for the response, Just tried it and no luck so far. Not sure if it will have conflicts when this is the only plugin I am using on a fresh install of wordpress.

Comment: @Poyi So it's not the root cause. Cna you take a look your browser sources panel and see if your files are there ?

Comment: @Ricardo Lohmann, yea it appears that the responsiveSlides js, css and jquery are loaded properly.

Comment: could it be a jquery version issue? Right now it's using 1.8.3 as specify on the responsiveSlides site.

Comment: @Ian: Good point. I'd take a peek inside responsiveSlides and check that it does define that function... should be defined as `$.fn.responsiveSlides` if memory serves.

Comment: It is defined in the file. I tried the plugin outside the wordpress and it works. Begin to think it's some sort of wordpress issue.